# Adding new row to table with three columns Javascript html click function

Tags: javascript, html, click, draggable

> Desrciption

I'd like to able to add a row using javascript with three columns to a table in html. 
I am creating a table where the user can enter their own text and add the text along with two other pieces of information to the table into three columns. The current code that I have will not display the new row. The code also includes a drag and drop feature where the user can click on the row and drag it into a different position into the table.
I am asking for guidance as to why when I press the click button it does not add a new row to the table.
edit: Code is now working after update, but the else statement does not do anything.

> Javascript

```
 function addRow(mytable) {
 var food = document.createTextNode(document.querySelector('.input').value);
 var category = document.createTextNode(document.querySelector('.input2').value);
 var time = document.createTextNode(document.querySelector('.input3').value);
 document.querySelector('.input').value = '';
  document.querySelector('.input2').value = '';
   document.querySelector('.input3').value = '';
  // Get a reference to the table
  if (food !== '') {
  var tableRef = document.getElementById(mytable);
  var attr = document.createAttribute('draggable');
  attr.value = 'true';
  // Insert a row at the end of the table
  var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1);
  newRow.setAttributeNode(attr);
  newRow.className = 'draggable';

  // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
  var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

   var newText = food;
   var newText2 = category;
   var newText3 = time;

  newCell.appendChild(newText);
  newCell2.appendChild(newText2);
  newCell3.appendChild(newText3);
  addEventsDragAndDrop(newRow);
   }
   //not working for some reason
   else {
     document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Please enter a name";
   }
}
```

> javascript click

```
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function( {addRow('mytable');});
```

> HTML

```
<table id="mytable">
                   <tr>
                     <th>Component</th>
                     <th>Category</th>
                     <th>Time</th>
                   </tr>

                   <div id="addRow"></div>

                </table>
```

Comment: On this line: `newCell.appendChild(newText)`, `newText` is a string, and `appendChild` expects TextNode object. You should see an error message in the console.

Comment: Thank you was very helpful to know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few adjustments below, but more detail needed, atm only one text input for component, but can add more for cook/time

```js
function addRow(mytable) {
             var newItem = document.createTextNode(document.querySelector('.input').value);
             var category = document.createTextNode("Cook");
             var time = document.createTextNode("time");
             document.querySelector('.input').value = '';
          // Get a reference to the table
           if (newItem != '') {
              var tableRef = document.getElementById(mytable);
              var attr = document.createAttribute('draggable');
              attr.value = 'true';
          // Insert a row at the end of the table
              var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1);
              newRow.setAttributeNode(attr);
              newRow.className = 'draggable';

          // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
              var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
              var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
              var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

              var newText =  newItem;
              var newText2 =  category;
              var newText3 = time;

              newCell.appendChild(newText);
              newCell2.appendChild(newText2);
              newCell3.appendChild(newText3);
              addEventsDragAndDrop(newRow);
           }
        }
        
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){addRow('mytable');});
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
                   <tr>
                     <th>Component</th>
                     <th>Category</th>
                     <th>Time</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr class="draggable" id="draggable" draggable="true">
                   <td>Food goes here</td>
                   <td>Cook</td>
                   <td>10</td>
                 </tr>

                   <div id="addRow"></div>

                </table>
                
                
                                <label for='component'>component</label>
                <input class='input' id='component' />
                <button id='btn'>add component</button>
```

Comment: Yes it works like this thank you, I have a click button inside the text box and your code some how duplicates the user entry text box inside the table. I will however incorporate this code to make it work. I may add more to time and cook but what I am going to do is match the input with an ajax drop down and pull that data from a database.